# Replacing .innerhtml text with a value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, innerhtml

i'm a beginning website programmer, and i'm stuck at replacing innerhtml text with the user's name. if the website loads, and the user doesn't have any name typed in, he get's an message saying to type his name. in a tutorial they used a alert to say welcome, but i wan't to do it with text on page. i tried to use .innerhtml with the value, but that didn't work. i can't find anything on the web either. does someone know what to do? i wrote the code like this:

```
<script>
          
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {

                var d = new Date();

                d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
                document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
            }
            function getCookie(cname) {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
                var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
                for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                    var c = ca[i];
                    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                        c = c.substring(1);
                }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
            }
            function checkCookie() {
                var user=getCookie("username");
                if (user != "") {
                    "document.getElementById("welcomemessage").innerhtml = "(user)";
                } else {
                    user = prompt("What is your name?","");
                    if (user != "" && user != null) {
                        setCookie("username", user, 30);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
    </script>
<p id="welcomemessage"></p>`
```

Comment: The developer tools will point out the error. Learn to use the developer tools in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("welcomemessage").innerHTML = "(" + user + ")";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("welcomemessage").innerText = "(" + user + ")";
```

with template literal:

```
document.getElementById("welcomemessage").innerHTML = `(${user})`
```

Remove the quotation mark at the beginning of `document.getElementById`, change `innerhtml` to `innerHTML` and set the value as I showed above.